# can i Dubai stopover package (from US/Canada) even your ticket from air canada and from dubai you are taking emirates air

Tags: dubai, stopovers, emirates

can i Dubai stopover package (from US/Canada) even your ticket from air canada and from dubai you are taking emirates air

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking about stopping over (layover or transit) in Dubai?

Comment: Related: [How do you book an Emirates Dubai stopover package (from US/Canada)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71804/3221)

Answer (score 1):

Emirates has a service named [Dubai Connect](https://www.emirates.com/ca/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/dubai-connect/) which will provide a free hotel and transfers for passengers who have a connection time between 8 and 24 hours (6 to 24 hours for first and business). But it is not available if one segment of the flight is Air Canada. Both segments must be on Emirates or Qantas.

From the [terms and conditions](https://www.emirates.com/ca/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/dubai-connect/terms-and-conditions/):

> Both your inbound and outbound flights to and from Dubai must be an Emirates flight (marketed by Qantas or Emirates) or a Qantas flight (marketed by Emirates or Qantas). Codeshare flights are not eligible other than EK5000 and QF8000 flights. The offer is not available on flights with other airlines and/or where Emirates is the marketing carrier only.
>
> The itinerary must be a single booking and ticketed on one ticket. The ticket must be issued on an Emirates (176) document or a Qantas (081) document.

You can still [obtain a UAE visa through Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/ca/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/) and book a hotel yourself, or you can [purchase a stopover package](https://www.emirates.com/ca/english/discover-dubai/dubai-stopover/) from Emirates, or you can stay in an airside hotel without a visa.